# How do I get compose key work in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am using Debian testing (wheezy) with emacs23. I mapped compose key to the right Windows key (Multi_key). The compose key works in shell, but not in emacs. How do I tell emacs to honor it?

Comment: what is compose key? okay I googled it, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key

Comment: I know I'm supposed to use emacs input methods, but I'm already used to the compose key...

Comment: What specifically does it do?

Comment: The compose key? It let's you input UTF mfs such as č,ô,☺,ß,ġ,ç,¡,¿,ə,→,←,µ etc. wo. charmap or 20 kb. layouts to rock w. around. I'm just using it now to type this. But in emacs under X, bang, nothing. I gg-d it for hours before asking here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm addicted to the compose key and am using Debian while developping Emacs, so if the compose key doesn't work in your case, it's a weird bug.  Please report it via M-x report-emacs-bug, providing as much detail as you can so we can try and reproduce it.

Answer (score 7):

Based on my email, [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283394/stefan) divined, that I lacked 'include "%L"' line in my custom ~/.XCompose file:

> IOW my crystal ball tells me that your .XCompose file is lacking
>   a `include "%L"' so it overrides the default rather than extends it.
>   And you don't notice it in Iceweasel because you haven't set the envvar
>   GTK_IM_MODULE=xim, so those apps don't actually use your .XCompose
>   file anyway.

Adding include "%L" to my ~/.XCompose solved the problem. (I actually went to install [Kragen's famous .XCompose file](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose) instead of my home made one.)

Comment: If I could, I'd give you a kiss on the cheeks !
I've been struggling with this for such a long time that I had already given up.